# Putting facebook like box into dreamweaver and not loading

Tags: dreamweaver, facebook-likebox

Hey I am trying to get a like box onto a page. When I put in the code facebook gives me (which is Iframe) everything seems fine however when I preview it (Chrome, IE, Firefox, Safari) it says the webpage cannot be found. It's driving me up the wall! What am I doing wrong!

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F%23%21%2Fpages%2FGarlands-Restaurant-Bar-Grill%2F206020489468223&amp;width=192&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=590" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:192px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the src the prefix **http:** is missing. Try this instead:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F%23%21%2Fpages%2FGarlands-Restaurant-Bar-Grill%2F206020489468223&amp;width=192&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=590" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:192px; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```