# Facebook plugin not showing on my browser

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, dreamweaver, facebook-likebox

As my title says my facebook plugin with the like button and faces is not showing when I preview my page in a browser using dreamweaver, must I upload the page to a server before I can see the results or should I be able to see the plugin when I preview with my browser?

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883448/putting-facebook-like-box-into-dreamweaver-and-not-loading
Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your website has to been online. I don't know how it works exactly, but you need an internetconnection because the like box on your website extracts its information from facebook. So if your website isn't online, it cannot connect with the facebook-platform.